# With find_all I just want to pull the data that has an argument

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

With find_all I just want to pull the class "searchResultsItem", but the class comes with the "searchResultsItem nativeAd classicNativeAd".

class only "searchResultsItem" how can I pull

```
hepsi = source.find_all("tr",attrs ={"class":"searchResultsItem"})
```

```html
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> ... </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> ... </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem nativeAd classicNativeAd> ... </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> ... </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, for example, CSS selector for filtering:

```
txt = '''<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> OK1 </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> OK2 </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem nativeAd classicNativeAd"> NOT OK! </tr>
<tr data-id="754490426" class="searchResultsItem"> OK3 </tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for tr in soup.select('tr.searchResultsItem:not(.nativeAd, .classicNativeAd)'):
    print(tr)
```

Prints:

```
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> OK1 </tr>
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> OK2 </tr>
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> OK3 </tr>
```

Comment: I am grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
hepsi = soup.find_all("tr")
for t in hepsi:
    if len(t['class'])==1:
        print(t)
```

Output:

```
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> ... </tr>
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> ... </tr>
<tr class="searchResultsItem" data-id="754490426"> ... </tr>
```